# User auth in Sequelize + Express REST API

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, passport.js

I am a beginner as a back-end developer with Node.js and I have the duty to build a REST API to deal with table tennis tournaments. 
The problem is that one of the premises demands user authentication. I am using MySQL (one of the premises of the test) and Sequelize as ORM . 

I've defined a User model with Sequelize, like so

```
const { hashSync, genSaltSync } = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
    hooks: {
      beforeCreate(user) {
        const salt = genSaltSync(10);
        user.password = hashSync(user.password, salt);
      },
    }
  });
  User.associate = function({ Match, Tournament }) {
    this.hasMany(Match, { as: 'matches', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
    this.belongsToMany(Tournament, { foreignKey: 'userId', through:'User_Tournament', as: 'tournaments', onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
  };
  return User;
};
```

As I need a token-based strategy* to deal with user's incoming requests, I I'd like some suggestions about how to store this information into the database nicely. I thought about a User_Token table, but don't really know if this is a good choice. 

* There's **no need for user sessions but tokens** to be set in the response header.
All sorts of suggestions are welcome.
Thanks.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Are you asking how to manage sessions with this stack? Please edit your question and be more concise.

Comment: I've edited it in order to be more concise. In fact, I need a good strategy/approach to deal with tokens with this stack. Maybe save as a column into User's table or create a table with the user_id and token, for example. Thank you!

Comment: Read up on PassportJS and the JWT strategy.

Comment: Thanks, Paul, I am reading up on this as you said. It's cool to easily set a middleware to check if the user is authenticated and also generate a token, but I still have doubts about how to store in a consistent way this token in the database. Should a user have multiple tokens or only one with an expiration date?